# CoreOS - get docker container name by PID?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, coreos, nsenter

I have a list of PID's and I need to get their docker container name. Going the other direction is easy ... get PID of docker container by image name:

```
$ docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' {SOME DOCKER NAME}
```

Any idea how to get the name by PID?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$ docker ps -q | xargs docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}, {{.ID}}' | grep "^${PID},"
```

[EDIT]

> **Disclaimer** This is for "normal" linux. I don't know anything useful about CoreOS, so this may or may not work there.

Comment: if only docker name needed can add | awk '{print $2}' in the end :) thanks

Comment: For my current docker version I had to change {{.ID}} to {{.Id}}, seems the docker inspect output has changed slightly!

Comment: What is the `${PID}` in the grep regex do? I just tried this and the grep is not working.

Comment: @wheeler, it's the PID you're looking for. For example, if you're looking for PID 123, then you can  `export PID=123` before running the above command. Or you can just replace `${PID}` with `123`.

Comment: For full list and name use `docker ps -q | xargs docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}, {{.Id}} {{.Name}}'`

Answer (score 15):

Because @Mitar's comment suggestion deserves to be a full answer:

To get container ID you can use:

```
cat /proc/<process-pid>/cgroup
```

Then to convert the container ID to docker container name:

```
docker inspect --format '{{.Name}}' "${containerId}" | sed 's/^\///'
```

Answer (score 5):

... as a one-liner as well

`PID=20168; sudo docker ps --no-trunc | grep $(cat /proc/$PID/cgroup | grep -oE '[0-9a-f]{64}' | head -1) | sed 's/^.* //'`

Comment: or even shorter

PID=20168; sudo docker ps --no-trunc | grep $(grep -oE '[0-9a-f]{64}' /proc/$PID/cgroup | head -1) | sed 's/^.* //'

Comment: or even minimal faster :)

sudo docker ps --no-trunc | grep $(head -1 /proc/$PID/cgroup | grep -oE '[0-9a-f]{64}') | sed 's/^.* //'

a little explanation:

--no-trunc shows the container-id in a 64Bit Hash containing only Numbers and Characters from "a" to "f"

grep -oE '[0-9a-f]{64}' 

greps exactly for a 64 Bit hash and prints out the hash only

Comment: Please don't include additional information to your answer as a comment. Instead, please [edit] your answer to include this information in the answer itself, using [formatted-text](/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 2):

I use the following script to get the container name for any host PID of a process inside a container:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
# Prints the name of the container inside which the process with a PID on the host is.

function getName {
  local pid="$1"

  if [[ -z "$pid" ]]; then
    echo "Missing host PID argument."
    exit 1
  fi

  if [ "$pid" -eq "1" ]; then
    echo "Unable to resolve host PID to a container name."
    exit 2
  fi

  # ps returns values potentially padded with spaces, so we pass them as they are without quoting.
  local parentPid="$(ps -o ppid= -p $pid)"
  local containerId="$(ps -o args= -f -p $parentPid | grep docker-containerd-shim | cut -d ' ' -f 2)"

  if [[ -n "$containerId" ]]; then
    local containerName="$(docker inspect --format '{{.Name}}' "$containerId" | sed 's/^\///')"
    if [[ -n "$containerName" ]]; then
      echo "$containerName"
    else
      echo "$containerId"
    fi
  else
    getName "$parentPid"
  fi
}

getName "$1"
```

Comment: Which version of Docker are you using?

Comment: You can also use `cat /proc/<host pid>/cgroup` to get container ID, and then use `docker inspect --format '{{.Name}}' "$containerId" | sed 's/^\///'` to get name from ID.

Comment: As a one-liner, using @Mitar 's idea: `docker inspect --format '{{.Name}}' "$(cat /proc/$PID/cgroup |head -n 1 |cut -d / -f 3)" | sed 's/^\///'`