# How to retrieve docker container name from pid of docker exec on the host (MacOS)

Tags: macos, docker

I'm trying to find out the name of a docker container given the pid of the `docker exec` command on the host. host system is MacOS (Catalina, but that shouldn't matter).
This information is available in a script I am writing, but it's the starting point, just as if you would do

```
localhost $ ps ax | grep docker | grep what-i-am-looking.for
 8968 ... docker exec [args...] [optional command]
```

If I inspect the running containers, the pid is not listed there.

```
 localhost $ docker ps -q | xargs docker inspect | grep 8968
 # nothing, so the PID is not stored
```

There's a different PID however

```
 localhost $ docker ps -q | xargs docker inspect '{{.State.Pid}}'
 31093
 6836
```

which has nothing to do with anything running on the host, nor inside docker (pids don't exist).

I can retrieve the Exec-IDs of running containers by

```
docker ps -q | xargs docker inspect -f '{{.ExecIDs}}'
```

or a bit more handy to work with

```
docker ps -q | xargs docker inspect | jq -r '.[0].ExecIDs[] | .'
```

and get some info about this via

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://docker/exec/$EXEC_ID/json
```

There's also a PID listed (a different one, like 31166), but this number has again nothing to do with the host.

**Any idea how to find out which container the command on the host belongs to?**

The alternative is to parse the `docker exec / run` command string, but due to the variety of arguments possible and optional commands that may be given I don't think it's a good idea.
For that I could check each word in the command string against the name found in one of the `docker inspect` calls, but I think it's too brittle.

BTW: [CoreOS - get docker container name by PID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406743/coreos-get-docker-container-name-by-pid) doesn't help since PIDs are different (see text( and there's no `/proc` on in MacOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach you're taking won't work on MacOS.  Parsing the `docker exec` command to find the first non-option argument is probably the only way to find this.

On MacOS, there is a hidden Linux VM that actually runs the containers.  This means there are *three* process ID namespaces (the host's, the VM's, and the container's).  The other important distinction is that the `docker exec` process isn't the same process as the process that's running inside the container.  So you're trying to match the MacOS host pid of the `docker exec` process against the Linux VM pid of the main container process, and they'll never match up.

You can get a shell inside the Linux VM (see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54804977/10008173)) and then the `docker inspect` pids will be visible.  But now, because of Docker's client-server architecture, there is no `docker exec` process; it only exists on the MacOS host.  You should be able to see the process it launches but it's hard to know that process comes from `docker exec`.

```
                   +------------------------------+
                   |             ................ |
docker exec ... ------> dockerd ---> process    : |
(host pid)         |   (VM pid)  :  (cont. pid) : |
                   |             ................ |
                   | Linux VM        (VM pid)     |
                   +------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the well done explanation. I was trying to figure out how to reach out to the VM, but as you stated there won't be any possibility to really match with the host pid. I did a greedy approach now matching all the arguments in the command line with any running docker container name and pick the one that fits first. Not perfect, but I think easier than trying to parse with optional and variable length command arguments.