# Where does a background docker container run? (MacOS)

Tags: linux, docker, process

I'm kind of new to Docker and Linux. I was wondering what does "running in background" means when it comes to containers since I can't find a process that relates to a background RUNNING container.

I ran htop filtered on `docker` and started 2 containers:

1. `docker run nginx`
   --> As I expected, a process appeared in htop (child of the shell who launched it)
2. `docker run -d nginx` --> Nothing appeared here (the container IS running though)

I couldn't find any explanation (I'm probably just not looking where I should...). What is happening here ?

EDIT:

I eventually figured out the "issue" which, as usual, lay between my chair and my keyboard: I'm running a headless linux VM on macOS and it didn't occur to me (until now (╬ಠ益ಠ)) that I wasn't launching my commands on the VM but directly on my host OS.

So under the hood docker on macOS was using its own linux VM and my `htop` command only listed the one linked to an opened 'host' terminal...

See [How to retrieve docker container name from pid of docker exec on the host (MacOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63337138/how-to-retrieve-docker-container-name-from-pid-of-docker-exec-on-the-host-macos)

Comment: `since I can't find a process that relates to a background RUNNING container.` where and how do you search?

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk, as I stated I'm using `htop` and its `Filter` function. I filtered using the keywords "docker" and "nginx" (not simultaneously obviously)

Comment: as what user? use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878808/finding-docker-container-processes-from-host-point-of-view

Comment: Thanks for the link, it did help me in the end :). I edited my post. I blame myself for not specifying right at the start that I was working on linux but under MacOS, i think someone would've spotted my mistake right away... I raised a duplicate flag

Comment: "lied"? I think the word you wanted was "lay".

Comment: It was obviously

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers are, in the end, just processes. It's possible for a container to die though.

If you do `docker run -d nginx` it'll print out a long hexadecimal string. That's the ID of the new container. You can run `docker logs <container-id>` to get the logs, e.g. `docker logs 123456`. You don't need the whole ID, just the first few characters will work.

You can see running containers using `docker ps`, and see all containers (alive and dead) using `docker ps -a`.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I can't see how that answers my question ^^'. My point is: `docker run nginx` seems to appear in `htop` as a process while `docker run -d nginx` does not. I'm not killing the containers, they both appear when I `docker container ls` (without the `-a`, which proves they are indeed running)

Comment: `nginx` is probably dying. I can't tell you why, but `docker logs` might be able to!

Comment: Both containers are running (`docker container ls` - without `-a` - lists both, I can interact with them, access logs, etc). I added the logs to my post in case it helps